# jQuery/JavaScript: Reorder Unordered List via Dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, html-lists

I have an unordered list `<ul>` with list items `<li>` which I'd like to be able to "reorder" via dragging. I'm using jQuery. How could I accomplish this? I tried hooking into the click event but I can't get the drag to work right (I want the other `<li>` elements to move out of the way once I drag an `<li>` element over a suitable spot so the user can see where it would end up).

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need to invent the wheel:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable

Comment: I looked at this but I couldn't find any example on how to make it work with an unordered list...

Comment: @Alex: that demo infact deals with an unordered list

Comment: Looks like the SO new answer notification doesn't work on an iPhone. :). +1

Comment: lol, now that you changed the link from draggable to sortable :)  Didn't know about sortable before. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered jQuery UI's droppable/draggable functionality?

Here's a link to a ul demo.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable